# Here the class Main is throwing DERIVED without declaring Main as THROWS but it works, can anyone explain this

Tags: java

Here the class Main is throwing DERIVED without declaring Main as THROWS but it works, can anyone explain this.

```
class Base extends Exception {}
    class Derived extends Base  {}
     public class Main {//main class throwing DERIVED
     public static void main(String args[]) {
       // some other stuff
       try {
           // Some monitored code
           throw new Derived();
        }
        catch(Base b)     { 
           System.out.println("Caught base class exception"); 
        }
        catch(Derived d)  { 
           System.out.println("Caught derived class exception"); 
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Because you are catching it.. Try removing those `catch` blocks

Comment: The `main` method does not `throw` the exception to the caller.  (It catches and handles it itself.) Therefore it does not need to declare that it throws it.

Comment: it is throwing in a try..catch block, the exception is caught in the "catch Derived d" statement and prints out. After that, program execution continues normally

Comment: As a side note, this code would not compile. The exception would have been already caught by `Base b`, and so `Derived d` is dead code.